# Is it possible to repeat a gate in structural verilog?

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I'm going to cascade several buffers in Verilog. My sample is as below which I've define 16 buffers which are cascaded in structural definition:

```
BUFX12 BUF01(dummy_wire[1],N62878);
BUFX12 BUF02(dummy_wire[2],dummy_wire[1]);
BUFX12 BUF03(dummy_wire[3],dummy_wire[2]);
BUFX12 BUF04(dummy_wire[4],dummy_wire[3]);
BUFX12 BUF05(dummy_wire[5],dummy_wire[4]);
BUFX12 BUF06(dummy_wire[6],dummy_wire[5]);
BUFX12 BUF07(dummy_wire[7],dummy_wire[6]);
BUFX12 BUF08(dummy_wire[8],dummy_wire[7]);
BUFX12 BUF09(dummy_wire[9],dummy_wire[8]);
BUFX12 BUF10(dummy_wire[10],dummy_wire[9]);
BUFX12 BUF11(dummy_wire[11],dummy_wire[10]);
BUFX12 BUF12(dummy_wire[12],dummy_wire[11]);
BUFX12 BUF13(dummy_wire[13],dummy_wire[12]);
BUFX12 BUF14(dummy_wire[14],dummy_wire[13]);
BUFX12 BUF15(dummy_wire[15],dummy_wire[14]);
```

Since I'm going to change number of buffers in my test design, I'm looking for a syntax such as for-loop to implement below structure in automated format but I don't know the correct structure for this.
I want to know if is it possible and what is the correct syntax.
Besides It would be better that implementation have names for instances.

Comment: Look for Verilog and 'generate'. If you have the choice switch to System Verilog as generates are much easier there:  `for (l=1; l<n; l++) BUFX12 bufx(w[l],w[l-1]); ` Input is w[0], output is w[n-1].

Comment: @Oldfart Generates much easier in SV? How so? (They were simplified in Verilog-2005, but the only thing I can think of that SV adds is the ability to declare your genvar inside the for loop.)

Comment: @Oldfart I'm using this syntax but it does not accept instance names have dimensions: `genvar i;
 for (i=1;i<15;i = i+1)
 begin
  BUFX12 buf[i] (dummy_wire[i+1],dummy_wire[i]);
 end` however removing instance names will fix the issue. like this `BUFX12 (dummy_wire[i+1],dummy_wire[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generate loop if you wish, but the array of instances solution offered by @toolic is more compact:

```
  assign dummy_wire[0] = N62878;

  generate
    genvar g;
    for (g=1; g<16; g=g+1)
      begin : in_Verilog_2001_you_need_this_and_it_needs_a_name
        BUFX12 BUF(dummy_wire[g],dummy_wire[g-1]);
      end
  endgenerate
```

Verilog-2005 relaxed the rules regarding `generate`. This is legal in Verilog-2005:

```
  assign dummy_wire[0] = N62878;

  genvar g;
  for (g=1; g<16; g=g+1)
    BUFX12 BUF(dummy_wire[g],dummy_wire[g-1]);
```

And in SystemVerilog, you could tidy it up a little bit more:

```
  assign dummy_wire[0] = N62878;

  for (genvar g=1; g<16; g++)
    BUFX12 BUF(dummy_wire[g],dummy_wire[g-1]);
```

But personally, I like the Verilog-2001 version: it's more explicit.

**MCVE**:

```
module M;

  wire [15:0] dummy_wire;
  wire N62878;

  assign dummy_wire[0] = N62878;

  generate
    genvar g;
    for (g=1; g<16; g=g+1)
      begin : in_Verilog_2001_you_need_this_and_it_needs_a_name
        BUFX12 BUF(dummy_wire[g],dummy_wire[g-1]);
      end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/YWw

Answer (score 5):

Use an array of instances:

```
wire [15:1] other = {dummy_wire[14:1], N62878};
BUFX12 BUF [15:1] (dummy_wire, other);
```

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite this sample using for-loop as I mentioned in comments of my question?

Comment: I'm going to write my design to be parametric. I want to declare something like `n` so that number of gates to be cascaded would be `n`. In this syntax `genvar i; for (i=1;i<15;i = i+1) begin BUFX12 buf[i] (dummy_wire[i+1],dummy_wire[i]);` I only need to change 15 so everything would be ok. But my problem is that I could not define `buf[i]` names so it would lead error in compiler

Comment: The code I posted can use a parameter instead of 15 and 14.  Give it a try.